# Use variable value in referencing variables

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
var seaSlt1 = "Init1";
var seaSlt2 = "Init2";
var seaSlt3 = "Init3";
var seaSlt4 = "Init4";
var seaSlt5 = "Init5";
var seaSlt6 = "Init6";

    for(var i=1;i<7;i++)
    {

        alert(seaSlt+i);
    }
 </script>
```

Why the result is nothing?

The correct result should be:

```
Init1
Init2
Init3
Init4
Init5
Init6
```

And I tried another way for:

```
alert("seaSlt"+i);
```

But the result is :

```
seaSlt1
seaSlt2
seaSlt3
seaSlt4
seaSlt5
seaSlt6
```

It is fail. It seems nothing wrong, who can help me?

Comment: You should use an array.

Answer (score 3):

If you have global variables you can access them with the [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object:

```js
var seaSlt1 = "Init1";
var seaSlt2 = "Init2";
var seaSlt3 = "Init3";
var seaSlt4 = "Init4";
var seaSlt5 = "Init5";
var seaSlt6 = "Init6";

for(var i=1;i<7;i++)
{
    console.log(window["seaSlt"+i]);
}
```

However, for that type of information an array is far more appropriate:

```js
const seasSlt = ["Init1", "Init2", "Init3", "Init4", "Init5", "Init6"];

for(var i = 0; i < seasSlt.length; i++){
    console.log(seasSlt[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats not how referencing a variable works.

alert(seaSlt+i);

For the above line the interpreter will first try to find seaSlt variable then it will try to add the value of i to it. Since seaSlt is not a variable present thats why you are getting nothing.

As mentioned above Array is the perfect use case for it.. 
 You can iterate through entire array by using simple for loop.